# Set the gravity of an element when zooming?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, inject

I'm injecting an iframe into a webpage, to act as a toolbar for another element, but unfortunately the elements act weirdly when zooming. The toolbar seems to gravitate towards the topleft corner, and the element towards the top-center. This means when zooming in they go into each other, and when zooming out they go way too far apart. is there any way to set this gravity?

Comment: Gravity? That is a new term. :)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm "injecting" it into the webpage. It's a chrome extension and I'm inserting a toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see a jsfiddle so I know exactly what you want, but just use fixed positioning.